# Voltage across the capacitors

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

This is a solved  example from the book "Practical Electronics for Inventors" I did not understand how the voltages across the two capacitors  come to 9V when circuit is switched to A and then switched to B for the second time

[image]

Comment: Please note that the schematic isn't really correct. The waveforms you show assume that there is some resistance in the wiring between the capacitors but that resistance is not shown explicitly in the schematic. When you connect the two capacitors in parallel some energy is lost in that resistance.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I agree, the capacitor waveforms imply a charging resistor but, if you did the analysis formulaicly and took the resistor value down towards zero ohms you would find that the same energy is lost no-matter what resistor value is chosen.

Comment: @Andyaka You can't do it formulaicly **as shown**. Connecting two capacitors in parallel, with different voltages, violates our definition of "parallel elements". Without a resistor one or both of the capacitor voltages must change instantly, so dV/dt is infinite and the capacitor current is infinite. In that case the formula falls apart and we get no useful information from it. If you say "take the resistor **towards** zero" then you are really saying "add a nonzero resistor to the circuit", as I did.

Comment: Exactly, you can't hope to properly analyse two perfect capacitors being connected with that annoying infinite current flow. Here's the point: No matter what value resistor you choose (assuming non zero), the same energy is lost in that resistor as the capacitor voltages slide into each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charge built up in C1 becomes subsequently shared with C2 and this changes the "common" voltage from 10 volts to 6.8 volts.

Note that the initial difference in voltage between the two capacitors (10 volts) becomes 6.8 volts i.e. any difference in voltage (such as when it happens the next cycle) is subject to a reduction of 0.68.

So, the next time this happens, C2 is at 6.8 volts and the difference between this and 10 volts is 3.2 volts so, subjecting this new difference voltage to a multiplication by 0.68 means that it becomes 2.176 volts.

In other words C2 charges a further 2.176 volts from 6.8 volts to 8.977 volts.

Or, put another way, at the final hurdle the total charge is 0.01 + 0.003196 = 0.013196 coulombs. So divide this by total capacitance (1470 uF) to get 8.977 volts.

Comment: Then tell him how many kilowatts are switched if every part has 1mΩ

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist easy; you know the energy lost when paralleling capacitors and you know the CR time and you can estimate average power for 1 CR time period.

Comment: Where does the lost energy go? Ideal capacitors are lossless, ideal switches have no resistance, and unless you created matter you can't destroy energy.

Comment: It's a conundrum for sure but energy is lost because no-matter what resistor value you choose and no matter how low you take that resistor value, the energy lost in the resistor is always constant hence accounting for that loss of energy even if the circuit is drawn as ideal. You have to think out the box.